# Plot with constraints

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can I plot `Plot3D[{1/(2 Sqrt[2] x y)}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` such that the only portion gets plotted for which $x^2 + y^2 =1$?

Comment: Use a [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) like this `Plot3D[{1/(2 Sqrt[2] x y)}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1]]` . Bear in mind I've used $\leq1$ not $=1$ because $=1$ would produce a line too thin to show up on a `Plot3D`. If you want this, you're better off using a parametric plot.

Comment: Restricted to the circle boundary it would look like this `ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, 1/(2 Sqrt[2] x y)} /. {x -> Cos[θ],  y -> Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, BoxRatios -> 1]`

Comment: @flinty `{θ, 0, π/2}`

Comment: @cvgmt that's only a quarter circle, but I suppose that's what OP wanted given {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}

Answer (score 1):

Use `MeshFunctions` `x^2+y^2` and set `Mesh` to `{{1}}`.

```
Plot3D[1/(2 Sqrt[2] x y), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2],
  Mesh -> {{1}}, MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> None, 
 ClippingStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

workaround `RegionFunction` ( see @flinty's comment )

```
Plot3D[{1/(2 Sqrt[2] x y)}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y },
    Evaluate[ grad = Grad[ x^2 + y^2 - 1, {x, y }]; -.02 Sqrt[grad . grad ] <= x^2 + y^2 - 1 <= .02 Sqrt[grad . grad ] ]]
, Mesh -> False , ClippingStyle -> None , BoundaryStyle -> None ]
```

[image]